# Printing friends list off Facebook with just their names

Tags: facebook, friends, printing, friend-list

Is there a way to print your Facebook Friends List?  Not their information, just the names on your list.

It would make it much easier to see who you lost when your amount of friends changes if you could have a list of who you are friends with.  After you have so many, it is hard to determine.

Comment: Load all your friends, from your profile page, and click `Ctrl + P`

Answer (score 1):

Using the API is an option when tied into a Facebook app.

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

That query will only produce user IDs, but that would solve your problem. You can also use the graph API to expand on that if you pick up your own access token.

This query will allow you to find usernames for each ID. Alternatively, you could use the full API to write your own script that will pull a JSON string for you. More details in the link below.

```
SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id=XXXXXXXX
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

This page will allow you to run these queries without being logged in. Parsing the data is up to you.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's **Download Your Information** option (under **Account** >> **Account Settings** >> **Download a copy** of your Facebook data) creates (among other things) a stripped down HTML file (**friends.html** in my July version) with a text list of your friends' names.

Comment: While this is *true*, it's an unnecessarily laborious process to accomplish something simple. If you're heavily active on Facebook, that download might be several gigs and take several hours to generate, all for just an HTML file...

Comment: Indeed, an approach that allows you to select which information to download would be preferable